# Mysql Optimization and scalling to have heavy load

Tags: php, mysql, sql, caching

I had a dedicated database server with 4 core CPU, 16GB ram. I tweaked alot to optimize mysql. When i run a query, it is taking 8 seconds to complete. And the same query executes in my local machine in 2 seconds. Could not able to figure out this weird behavior.

Would be great if anyone of you can help me out of this.

Thanks,

Comment: Post the relevant code please

Comment: Production server can be slower because: 1) It got a lot more data, 2) There are many connections open to it processing many requests in concurrence/parallel, 3) You are not using realistic parameter at you test queries (like you are testing the return of a few rows and real users are getting millions). First thing to do is comparing query plans from both machines, for sure that ill give you a clue.